# How to push code or repository to remote URL like gerrit by Android studio

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using Android studio for my projects . Can anyone help me how to push code from local repository to remote URl by Android studio

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to push code with Android Studio's git GUI, right? If so, set `remote.<name>.push` in gitconfig. `name` defaults to `origin`.

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
```

With this value, `git push origin master` is translated to `git push origin master:refs/for/master`.

Make sure that your code is always on a branch whose name exactly matches with the real branch in the remote repository. If the code is on a detached HEAD, or on a local-only branch, this configuration value does not work and you'll have to run explicitly `git push HEAD:refs/for/foo` in the console.